# hive is not running in local mode in Cloudera Distribution?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh

When I am trying to run the start the hive I am getting following error, I am using cdh 5.12 in local mode

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient**

Below is my hive-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>
          jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    </value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description></property>

<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
     <value>thrift://127.0.0.1:9083</value>
    <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of  the    metastore host</description>
</property>
```

Also I don't have access to cloudera manager

Comment: 1) Add the entire error from the Hive metastore logs 2) Please verify Mysql and the metastore process are actually running